# Ubuntu 14.04 and Kodi issues

Tags: software-installation, kodi

I cannot get kodi to operate on Linux.  constantly getting this error message.   Someone please tell me if I am doing something wrong.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
$ sudo apt-get update

...

Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main i386 Packages                         
  404  Not Found
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en_US                     
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Translation-en                        
Fetched 2,811 kB in 15s (182 kB/s)                                             
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/xbmc-ppa-build-depends/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/xbmc-ppa-build-depends/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: I assume the spaces in the `http://` lines were there to stop them auto-linking. I've converted the post to use our code formatting which stops that happening and have removed the extra spaces.

Comment: http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/xbmc-ppa-build-depends doesnt have a trusty repo - looks like a duplicate of our standard Q&A: http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-when-using-a-ppa-or-updating-my-package-lists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't quite gel with the output. You've added [the xbmc build dependency repo](https://launchpad.net/~team-xbmc/+archive/ubuntu/xbmc-ppa-build-depends) which isn't maintained and doens't have a Trusty version and that's why you're seeing errors.

Simply put, you don't need it for *using* xbmc or Kodi so don't use it. Get rid of it:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:team-xbmc/xbmc-ppa-build-depends
```

You just need the main xbmc/kodi repo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:team-xbmc/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kodi
```

Comment: ok i did that.  this time around I did not get any error messages.  However when I open kodi it opens for a opens for a second and then closes immediately.   Any pointers for that?